# Django: How to make a ListView which will take the parameters to build a list of questions on a different template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

The purpose of the project that I am working on is to fetch physics' questions according to what choices the user wants. The first choice is what topic the wanted questions belong to, and the other one is what type of questions, the questions belong to. However and with the help of different online sources, I have created the forms and they look great. But now I would like to get the results out of these forms, I know that I have to create a `view.py` for the results and make the `action` in my `HTML` files into `GET`. But I don't know how the view will look like.

This is the `model.py`
        from django.db import models
        from home.choices import *

```
    # Create your models here.

    class Topic(models.Model):
        topic_name = models.IntegerField(
                        choices = question_topic_name_choices, default = 1)
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.topic_name

    class Image (models.Model):
        image_file = models.ImageField()

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.image_file

    class Question(models.Model):
        questions_type = models. IntegerField(
                        choices = questions_type_choices, default = 1)
        question_topic = models.ForeignKey(    'Topic',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
        question_description = models.TextField()
        question_answer = models.ForeignKey(    'Answer',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
        question_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.question_type

    class Answer(models.Model):
        answer_description = models.TextField()
        answer_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.answer_description
```

This is the `form.py` which contains the select fields and from these select fields I want to get to the results.

```
    from django import forms
    from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
    from .models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
    from .choices import questions_type_choices, question_topic_name_choices

    class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
        topic_name      =   forms.ChoiceField(
                        choices=question_topic_name_choices,
                        widget = forms.Select(
                        attrs = {'class': 'home-select-one'}
                            ))

        class Meta:
            model = Topic
            fields = ['topic_name',]
            def __str__(self):
                return self.fields


    class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        questions_type =   forms.ChoiceField(
                        choices= questions_type_choices,
                        widget = forms.Select(
                        attrs = {'class': 'home-select-two'},
                            ))

        class Meta:
            model = Question
            fields = ['questions_type',]
            def __str__(self):
                return self.fields


    class QuizMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
        form_classes    =   {
                    'topics':TopicForm,
                    'questions':QuestionForm
        }
        def save(self, commit=True):
            objects = super(QuizMultiForm, self).save(commit=False)

            if commit:
                topic_name = objects['topic_name']
                topic_name.save()
                questions_type = objects['question_type']
                questions_type.topic_name = topic_name
                questions_type.save()
            return objects
```

This is my `views.py` for the forms.

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
    from django.views.generic import CreateView
    from home.models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
    from home.forms import QuizMultiForm



    def QuizView(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = QuizMultiForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                pass
        else:
            form = QuizMultiForm()
        return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

This is `html` file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
  {% block content %}
        <form  method="GET" action="views_results.py">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
        </form>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Here are my `urls.py`

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('ask/', ask_page_url, name = 'ask_page'),
        path('home/', home_page_url, name = 'home_page'),
        path('download/', download_url, name = 'download_page'),
    ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you implement the models? I strongly recommend you to read **Getting started with Django**, is a very good place to start and I promise you'll find there all that you need to learn the basics.

Comment: This  `<form  method="GET" action="results.html">` is definitely not right because in the `action` you should have url to your views not an html file.

Comment: I have added the `models.py` and `forms.py` used in my project.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass variables to template from template

In the main template

```
{% for question in questions %}
    {% include "main/q.html" with question=question %}
{% endfor %}
```

and in q.html

```
<h1>{{ question }}</h1>
```

Comment: The OP wants to know how to get those questions, nobody can't tell how to do that without having knowledge about the `Question` model (if any) or the form that is submitted.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I wish stackoverflow was filled with good people like you. Because you mentioned the reason for downvote. :D Otherwise people just downvote without giving the reason.

Comment: @Ahtisham Thanks, I've learned here in SO, that a good explanation for a downvote is as good as any answer.